# How is chrome plugin Evernote Clearly work?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, evernote

Recently I have been doing a reader module like Evernote Clearly plugin or Safari Reader. Is anybody knows how it work with javascript?

Please give me a hand...! Thx~!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it revolves around some parsers to web services or offline heuristic-based js, one of the e.g. is https://github.com/Kerrick/readability-js, readability.js are forked and maintain by nice guys, but generated content might not be as read friendly. The rest are css.

Comment: Thx for your help, I find a node.js version readability. It works : )